# PortfolioAnalytics [R] - optimize.portfolio.rebalancing / rebalancing period

Tags: optimization

I am having difficulties trying to set up the rebalancing period to semi-annual or every 9 months in the `optimize.portfolio.rebalancing` function in the package PortfolioAnalytics (R). Is it possible to add the factor $k=1,2$ (endpoints) in the rebalancing function?

I tried `optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(...rebalance_on=list("quarters",k=2)...)` and `optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(... ,rebalance_on="quarters", k=2, ...)`. However, I did not obtain semi-annual rebalancing periods and I only got the standard quarterly rebalancing period.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `k=6` to the `endpoints()` wrapper and use that function instead...

```
optimize.portfolio.rebalancing2 = function (R, portfolio = NULL, constraints = NULL, objectives = NULL, 
          optimize_method = c("DEoptim", "random", "ROI"), search_size = 20000, 
          trace = FALSE, ..., rp = NULL, rebalance_on = NULL, training_period = NULL, 
          rolling_window = NULL) 
{
  stopifnot("package:foreach" %in% search() || requireNamespace("foreach", 
                                                                quietly = TRUE))
  stopifnot("package:iterators" %in% search() || requireNamespace("iterators", 
                                                                  quietly = TRUE))
  if (inherits(portfolio, "portfolio.list")) {
    n.portf <- length(portfolio)
    opt.list <- vector("list", n.portf)
    for (i in 1:length(opt.list)) {
      if (hasArg(message)) 
        message = match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)$message
      else message = FALSE
      if (message) 
        cat("Starting optimization of portfolio ", i, 
            "\n")
      opt.list[[i]] <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R = R, 
                                                      portfolio = portfolio[[i]], constraints = constraints, 
                                                      objectives = objectives, optimize_method = optimize_method, 
                                                      search_size = search_size, trace = trace, ... = ..., 
                                                      rp = rp, rebalance_on = rebalance_on, training_period = training_period, 
                                                      rolling_window = rolling_window)
    }
    out <- combine.optimizations(opt.list)
    class(out) <- "opt.rebal.list"
    return(out)
  }
  if (inherits(portfolio, "mult.portfolio.spec")) {
    R <- proxy.mult.portfolio(R = R, mult.portfolio = portfolio)
    portfolio <- portfolio$top.portfolio
  }
  call <- match.call()
  start_t <- Sys.time()
  if (!is.null(portfolio) & !is.portfolio(portfolio)) {
    stop("you must pass in an object of class 'portfolio' to control the optimization")
  }
  if (hasArg(message)) 
    message = match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)$message
  else message = FALSE
  if (hasArg(trailing_periods)) {
    trailing_periods = match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)$trailing_periods
    rolling_window <- trailing_periods
  }
  if (!is.null(constraints)) {
    if (inherits(constraints, "v1_constraint")) {
      if (is.null(portfolio)) {
        tmp_portf <- portfolio.spec(assets = constraints$assets)
      }
      message("constraint object passed in is a 'v1_constraint' object, updating to v2 specification")
      portfolio <- update_constraint_v1tov2(portfolio = tmp_portf, 
                                            v1_constraint = constraints)
    }
    if (!inherits(constraints, "v1_constraint")) {
      portfolio <- insert_constraints(portfolio = portfolio, 
                                      constraints = constraints)
    }
  }
  if (!is.null(objectives)) {
    portfolio <- insert_objectives(portfolio = portfolio, 
                                   objectives = objectives)
  }
  call <- match.call()
  if (optimize_method == "random") {
    if (hasArg(rp_method)) 
      rp_method = match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)$rp_method
    else rp_method = "sample"
    if (hasArg(eliminate)) 
      eliminate = match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)$eliminate
    else eliminate = TRUE
    if (hasArg(fev)) 
      fev = match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)$fev
    else fev = 0:5
    if (is.null(rp)) 
      if (inherits(portfolio, "regime.portfolios")) {
        rp <- rp.regime.portfolios(regime = portfolio, 
                                   permutations = search_size, rp_method = rp_method, 
                                   eliminate = eliminate, fev = fev)
      }
    else {
      rp <- random_portfolios(portfolio = portfolio, 
                              permutations = search_size, rp_method = rp_method, 
                              eliminate = eliminate, fev = fev)
    }
  }
  else {
    rp = NULL
  }
  if (is.null(training_period) & !is.null(rolling_window)) 
    training_period <- rolling_window
  if (is.null(training_period)) {
    if (nrow(R) < 36) 
      training_period = nrow(R)
    else training_period = 36
  }
  if (is.null(rolling_window)) {
    ep.i <- endpoints(R, on = rebalance_on,k=6)[which(endpoints(R, 
                                                            on = rebalance_on) >= training_period)]
    ep <- ep.i[1]
    out_list <- foreach::foreach(ep = iterators::iter(ep.i), 
                                 .errorhandling = "pass", .packages = "PortfolioAnalytics") %dopar% 
      {
        optimize.portfolio(R[1:ep, ], portfolio = portfolio, 
                           optimize_method = optimize_method, search_size = search_size, 
                           trace = trace, rp = rp, parallel = FALSE, ... = ...)
      }
  }
  else {
    ep.i <- endpoints(R, on = rebalance_on,k=6)[which(endpoints(R, 
                                                            on = rebalance_on) >= training_period)]
    out_list <- foreach::foreach(ep = iterators::iter(ep.i), 
                                 .errorhandling = "pass", .packages = "PortfolioAnalytics") %dopar% 
      {
        optimize.portfolio(R[(ifelse(ep - rolling_window >= 
                                       1, ep - rolling_window, 1)):ep, ], portfolio = portfolio, 
                           optimize_method = optimize_method, search_size = search_size, 
                           trace = trace, rp = rp, parallel = FALSE, ... = ...)
      }
  }
  names(out_list) <- index(R[ep.i])
  end_t <- Sys.time()
  elapsed_time <- end_t - start_t
  if (message) 
    message(c("overall elapsed time:", end_t - start_t))
  out <- list()
  out$portfolio <- portfolio
  out$R <- R
  out$call <- call
  out$elapsed_time <- elapsed_time
  out$opt_rebalancing <- out_list
  class(out) <- c("optimize.portfolio.rebalancing")
  return(out)
}
```

Use the `rebalance_on="months"`

```
opt1 <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing2(R=R, portfolio=port1,optimize_method="DEoptim",itermax=10, 
                                       search_size=2000,trace=TRUE,rebalance_on = "months",
                                       training_period = 125,rolling_window = 125)
```